# Store sequence of records to a particular id in a database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table called imagedetails:

```
CREATE TABLE imagedetails (
  imageid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  imagename VARCHAR(50),
  studyid INTEGER,    
  FOREIGN KEY(studyid) REFERENCES study(studyid)
);
```

I input the following values:

```
INSERT INTO imagedetails VALUES (1,'img1.jpg',1);
INSERT INTO imagedetails VALUES (2,'img2.jpg',2);
INSERT INTO imagedetails VALUES (3,'imp3.jpg',3);
INSERT INTO imagedetails VALUES (4,'img4.jpg',4);
```

Right now the images are stored on the server, how can I store multiple images related to a specific ID?

Comment: Do you want multiple images for each imageid, or multiple images for each studyid?

Comment: You create a new table for storing image and add a foreign key to imageid/studyid to the existing tables.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, OP?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of ambiguity in your question.

However, if you want to be able to have multiple images for each study id, you don't have to change anything. There is already (what appears to be) a one-to-many relationship between the study table and the imagedetails table. In your inserts you set all of the studyids to be the same as the imageid, but that doesn't have to be the case.

For example, this is completely valid:

```
INSERT INTO imagedetails VALUES (1,'img1.jpg',1);
INSERT INTO imagedetails VALUES (2,'img2.jpg',1);
INSERT INTO imagedetails VALUES (3,'imp3.jpg',1);
INSERT INTO imagedetails VALUES (4,'img4.jpg',2);
```

And now you have 3 images associated with studyid 1, and 1 image associated with studyid 2.